# All records displayed in many to many django app

Tags: python, django

Here my models:

**django_zoom2/meetings/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from participants.models import Participant

class Meeting(models.Model):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='xxxx')
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(Participant)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.topic
```

**django_zoom2/participants/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
# from meetings.models import Meeting

class Participant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

..and the admin views:

**django_zoom2/meetings/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Meeting

@admin.register(Meeting)
class MeetingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['topic', 'uuid']
```

**django_zoom2/meetings/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Participant

@admin.register(Participant)
class ParticipantAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'email']
```

I have a single association with the meeting blarg:

```
>>> from meetings.models import Meeting
>>> m= Meeting.objects.get(id=1)
>>> m
<Meeting: blarg>
>>> m.participants.all()
<QuerySet [<Participant: molly@myorg.org>]>
```

...but in the view here is what I see:

[image]

Why am I seeing all the participants email addresses in this view? I only want to see the associated email addresses; in this case, there should be one. Molly.

Comment: Are you ok using an Inline?  Or are you wanting the participants query to return a particular meeting's subset of Participants in a select html control?

Comment: Anything is fine view wise, I just want to correct association returned. Right now it looks to be returning all participants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this should give you a list of Participants for each meeting as a Tabular inline.  You can edit the `extra=0` as needed.

In `meetings/admin.py`:

```
class AttendanceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Meeting.participants.through
    extra = 0

@admin.register(Meeting)
class MeetingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        AttendanceInline,
    ]
    exclude = ('participants',)
```

More [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models).

Comment: Which file should this go in?

Comment: `meetings/admin.py`

Comment: Great thanks! Actually, I feel kind of foolish...the interface I posted above was showing the correct associations, it was just showing the entire list and only highlighting those that had the association.

Comment: Yes, only a line or two away!  The `exclude` is key, but non-intuitive, and it's buried in the docs.